# How do you parse a substring from an Excel cell?

Tags: excel

I have a column with the following values:

```
month
201201     // means  January of 2012
201102     // means February of 2011
201203
201304
...
201307
201106
```

I need to create a new column that would be convert the last two numbers in the `month` column into the name of the month, so that `201201` will become `Jan-2012`, `201106` should become `Jun-2011`.

How can I parse the last two characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

=DATE(MID(A2,1,4),MID(A2,5,2),1)

Answer (score 2):

This gives you the formatting you want:

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT(A1,4),RIGHT(A1,2),1),"MMM-YYYY")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions and concatenate the results. Assuming the first value is in A2:

```
=(1&"-"&RIGHT(A2,2)&"-"&LEFT(A2,4))*1
```

And format the cell as `mmm-yyyy`.

This assumes that your regional settings have dates as `dd/mm/yyyy` format.

Otherwise, you'll have to switch the month and date around.

```
=(RIGHT(A2,2)&"-"&1&"-"&LEFT(A2,4))*1
```