# How to bring in string from left of numbers in Excel

Tags: string, excel

I'm trying to format a column based off of another (let's say column B2). The column contains a value like "ABC011" and I need to bring in just the letters "ABC".

For another column I also need to bring in just the numbers "011" but without the trailing zeroes (although I imagine that if I can get the solution for the first question I'll be able to figure out the second).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The length of the characters can change but the numbers are USUALLY 2 or more digits as well as the letters.

Comment: Is it always 3 letters 3 numbers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse a substring from an Excel cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19140710/how-do-you-parse-a-substring-from-an-excel-cell)

Comment: You could try using a regex in find and replace.  But you need to make your example more clear.

Comment: Unfortunately no, the string length varies and can sometimes be 2 letters, 2 numbers, etc.

Comment: Appended an edit for clarification. Hope that helps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To isolate the first characters from the numbers, in C2 this array formula:

```
=MID(B2,1,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2)),SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2)))-1)
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when leaving edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

**If you have excel 2010 or later** you can use this non CSE Formula instead of the one above. It does not require the Ctrl-Shift-Enter:

```
=MID(B2,1,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},B2),1)-1)
```

---

Then using that result in D2 we put:

```
=RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-LEN(C2))
```

This will put it in as a string, if yo want to make it a number just put `--` in front:

```
=--RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-LEN(C2))
```

This will return the number as a number so `011` will become `11`

To get the numbers

[image]